# Is it OK to call a girl petite?

Tags: meaning

Does *petite* have any connotations?

Is this word commendatory or derogatory?

Can it be used on a little girl? A female adult? A boy? A male adult?

Should it be used only on close friends or anyone you see?

Comment: In the general sense, I'd say you can more-or-less safely apply it to women (not men) you observe who are out of earshot. Saying it directly to a woman is risky and her response depends on her personal perceptions. For example, my sister-in-law is 5'2" (on a tall day) and maybe 102# soaking wet, and hates the appellation, because she's views herself as an imposing Amazon of a woman. Also, to be fair, she could kick my ass. And I'm not a small man. Similarly for my mother who is ~70 years old and 98# of spring-loaded muscle. I'm not kidding when I say you're taking a risk calling her *petite*.

Comment: (Also, though objectively larger [relatively] than my mother, I have no doubt you'd be motivated to call my sister-in-law "*petiter*" than her. You remember the *Seinfeld* episode about "man hands"? Yeah, well, don't bring that up, either.)

Comment: What DanBron said, and, I'd consider it derogatory.

Comment: @NVZ, "petite" is used in the apparel industry as a descriptive term for a certain range of clothing sizes. You can find many clothing items described as "petite", for instance at Amazon and other stores. Is there any particular reason you consider the term derogatory? It can be off-putting when society puts an excessive focus on women's body sizes and other physical characteristics, especially in situations where it is hardly relevant, but there are a few situations where it is indeed relevant and a widely-accepted descriptive term is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be used for girls or adult women, never for boys or adult men.

It is neutral and not derogatory. It simply refers to a small body size, and is often used when referring to clothing and clothing sizes. Note however that body size is sometimes a sensitive issue for some people.

See for instance [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/petite?s=t)

Comment: Thank you. This is a much better answer than *opinion-based*.